# Python Pandas: Unable to successfully remove rows containing values of only whitespace

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame containing address fields such as `NUMBER`, `STREET`, `POSTCODE` etc. I want to delete all the rows that contain `NaN`s or blanks in **any** of these columns.

The first part, removing the `NaN`-containing rows works fine with:

```
df = df.dropna(subset=["NUMBER","STREET","POSTCODE"]
```

But I'm having trouble with the blanks. I notice that some of the rows contain `""` values, and possibly `" "` and other "invisible" strings. I've tried the following approaches based on advice from other questions:

```
df.replace("",np.nan,inplace=True) # then using dropna

df.drop(df.loc[df["NUMBER"]==""].index, inplace=True) # then repeating for the other cols

df = df[df["NUMBER"].str.strip().astype(bool)] # then repeating for the other cols
```

But in all cases I still end up with empty values. I confirmed that at least some of the blanks are equal to the string `""` by using:

```
df["NUMBER"][index_with_blank] == "" # which returns: True

type(df["NUMBER"][index_with_blank]) # which returns: str
```

So now I'm not sure how to proceed in getting rid of all these rows. Many thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Replace no, one or multiple spaces to missing values and then remove rows:

```
df = df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True).dropna(subset=["NUMBER","STREET","POSTCODE"])
```

Or if need remove values in some columns and not change original DataFrame:

```
cols = ["NUMBER","STREET","POSTCODE"]
df = df[df[cols].replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True).notna().all(axis=1)]
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. I tried this and it removed some but not all of the blanks. I've confirmed that the blanks remaining are still strings equal to `""`.

Comment: @celery_gemini - Can you select not removed rows by index and convert to tuples for see what is problem? like `df.loc[[10, 11]].apply(tuple, 1)` ?

Comment: @celery_gemini - if not removed rows has index 10 and 11